# В чем ошибка? категории if python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Выводит сразу несколько категорий возрастов, например ввел 96 лет: мне выводит: молодость зрелость и только потом старость

```
age = int(input())
if age <= 13:
    print("детство")
if age >= 13 <= 24:
    print("молодость")
if age >= 25 <= 59:
    print("зрелость")
if age >= 91:
    print("старость")
```

Comment: elif после первого if

Comment: Или 14 во втором if. Пропущены and. Куда девались (60, 90)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если почти ничего не менять, можно сделать вот так:

```
age = int(input())
if age <= 13:
    print("детство")
if 13 < age <= 24: # Это эквивалентно 13 < age and age <= 24
    print("молодость")
if 24 < age <= 59:
    print("зрелость")
if 59 < age <= 90:
    pass # ?
if 90 < age:
    print("старость")
```

Но очевидно, что можно не проверять уже проверенные условия:

```
age = int(input())
if age <= 13:
    print("детство")
elif age <= 24:
    print("молодость")
elif age <= 59:
    print("зрелость")
elif age <= 90:
    pass # ?
else:
    print("старость")
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Очевидно, что границы удовлетворяют обоим условиям.
2. Нижнюю границу вообще не надо проверять - вместо этого надо использовать elif.
3. <s>Используй отладчик.</s>

Answer (score 5):

```
if age >= 25 <= 59:
```

происходит следующее:

если `age >= 25` и если `25 <= 59`

очевидно, что при `age >= 25` эти 2 условия выполняются всегда и соответственно условия ниже уже не выполняются

правильнее было бы написать

```
if 25 <= age <= 59:
```

ниже аналогично

Answer (score 3):

Ошибку вам уже нашли,а это так, для альтернативы

```
from bisect import bisect

def grade(age):
    breakpoints=[14, 25, 60, 91, 150]
    grades=["детство","молодость","зрелость","старость", "пророк"]
    return grades[bisect(breakpoints, age)]

for age in range(1,150,7):
    print(f"{age} - это {grade(age)}")
```

Подробности применения bisect() в подобных случаях в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).

Comment: Интересный подход, впрочем при небольших массивах обычный перебор может быть эффективнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, 
n/2 > log2(n) уже при n=5 ))

Comment: Вы не учитываете константы. Думаю, равновесие наступает при n побольше)

Comment: Это очень сложно, я еще преисполнился чтобы понять это, но ваш ответ меня обвораживает